# problem to publish xamarin aplication on google play

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to publish an app on google play and the following warning appears:

This APK has codes and resources that are not used and that are being sent to users. Reduce the size of your application with the Android App Bundle.

The application is developed with xamarin forms. I read about some settings but I am not very clear.

How can I solve this? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now play store not accepting apk. Please use vs 2019 to build your project, which will give you Android App Bundle. for more information : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IOZ0SUKZq4